# How can I refactor the containing loop with SqlCommand.ExecuteReader if multiple column result?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am getting an S1751 warning in Visual Studio 2019 'Refactor the containing loop to return more than one value'
There are a few occurrences when I have used ExecuteScalar to return the singular column's value but in this case, I need to return one row but four columns.

```
                sqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
                sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Total_Retirement_Need, Total_Social_Security, Total_Account_Income, Savings_And_Checking " +
                    "FROM tblA A INNER JOIN " +
                    "tblB B ON A.SessionId = B.SessionID " +
                    "WHERE A.SessionID = @sessionId " +
                    "AND B.Age = JSON_VALUE(formData, '$.goalData.clientARetireAgeText')";
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@sessionId", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = sessionId;
                sqlCommand.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        decimal Total_Retirement_Needed = reader.GetDecimal(0);
                        decimal Total_Social_Security = reader.GetDecimal(1);
                        decimal Total_Account_Income = reader.GetDecimal(2);
                        decimal Savings_And_Checking = reader.GetDecimal(3);
                        return ("$" + Total_Retirement_Needed.ToString("N0"),
                            "$" + Total_Social_Security.ToString("N0"),
                            "$" + Total_Account_Income.ToString("N0"),
                            "$" + Savings_And_Checking.ToString("N0")
                            );
                    }
                }
                reader.Close();
                return ("N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A");
```

I can't use ExecuteScalar and ExecuteReader gives me the warning. I could make it a stored procedure and if that is the 'A' answer I'll take it but looking for options.

Thanks!

Comment: Try [dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)

Comment: How many rows do you expect the query to return?  One? Or more than one?

Comment: just one row is going to be returned from the query

Comment: Then the warning is [indirectly] telling you that you only need an `if` statement, since it can't execute the loop more than once due to the `return`. Also, you can skip the `HasRows` test since `reader.Read()` will return `false` if `HasRows` is `false`.

Comment: First of all, make your SQL query to be return a single row you can do it by where condition or using Top 1
in the second step, you can use the SqlDataAdapter with DataTable to have access to each cell using the column name

Comment: Let me know if you want me to do the codding part for you.

Comment: Consider using `using` statements around your data objects. This will ensure the connection, command, and reader are properly disposed of should an error be encountered.

Comment: yeah, this is a code snippet, it is covered by Using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `while` loop, no need for it, just attempt the read. If the read is successful then you only need to read your first record.

```
SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.Read())
{
    decimal Total_Retirement_Needed = reader.GetDecimal(0);
    decimal Total_Social_Security = reader.GetDecimal(1);
    decimal Total_Account_Income = reader.GetDecimal(2);
    decimal Savings_And_Checking = reader.GetDecimal(3);
    return ("$" + Total_Retirement_Needed.ToString("N0"),
                        "$" + Total_Social_Security.ToString("N0"),
                        "$" + Total_Account_Income.ToString("N0"),
                        "$" + Savings_And_Checking.ToString("N0")
                    );
}
reader.Close();
```

You should also limit your SQL query results with a `Top x` clause. Since you only ever want one record there is no need to return any more than one.

```
SELECT TOP 1 Total_Retirement_Need, Total_Social_Security, Total_Account_Income...
```